# Google spreadsheet if weeknum yes/no not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to use this formula in google spreadsheet (B2 is a date, eg. 27.11.2020):

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(now()) = WEEKNUM(B2),"yes","no")
```

For some reason this is not possible.
When using only:

```
=WEEKNUM(now()) = WEEKNUM(B2)
```

*I do get TRUE/FALSE*, but I need to be able to convert the TRUE/FALSE to YES/NO.
Why does not this work and are there any alternatives?

Comment: the first formula works for me . For the second one you have an extra parenthesis. It should be: `=WEEKNUM(now()) = WEEKNUM(B2)` instead. But since the first one works, what is your question really? Also since `B2` is clearly part of this formula, why don't you tell us what is in `B2` ?

Comment: Sorry, there where a spelling error. B2 contains an European date, eg. 27.11.2020

Comment: I posted my answer. However, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64969077/edit) your question to add the last comment because it plays a crucial factor determining the solution to this question. Comments are rarely visible to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue:**

As you can see in the following screenshot or in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949?hl=en):

[image]

`WEEKNUM` accepts a date object but you are passing a string `27.11.2020`.

**Solution:**

You need to convert `27.11.2020` to an actual [date](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en) object.

You can do that by using this formula:

`=IF(WEEKNUM(now()) = WEEKNUM(date(right(B2,4),mid(B2,4,2),left(B2,2))),"yes","no")`

[image: output]

Comment: *"You need to convert `27.11.2020` to an actual date object."* **As a note**: You do not need to convert it to an actual date object. The cell's content just needs to **simulate the form/pattern** of an actual date object. Notice that although both  `=SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","/")` and `=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"\.","/")` results are text, Google is *"smart"* enough to extract the `WEEKNUM` as if the results were dates. This behaviour is sometimes problematic since both `11 2020` and `November 1` are interpreted as `11/1/2020` even when not desired.

Comment: @marikamitsos thanks for the info once again :) Didn't know that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(now())
   =WEEKNUM(REGEXREPLACE(B1,"\.","/")),"yes","no")
```

**OR**

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(now())
   =WEEKNUM(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".","/")),"yes","no")
```

[image]

---

**The above formulas work for both European as well as USA formats.**

Functions used:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)